# Ember.js Unable to get hasMany id when using .filter()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

It seems a no-brainer to me, but could not get this to work:

My **ApplicationRoute:**

```
model: function () {
    this.controllerFor('categories').set('model', this.store.find('category'));
}
```

**CategoriesController:**

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
```

**ArticlesRoute:** (using query-params-new)

```
model: function(params) {

    if (params.category) {
        return this.store.find('article').filter(function(item) {
            console.log(item.get('category.id'); // => undefined
            return (item.get('category.id') === params.category); // => always false
        });
    } else {
        return this.store.find('article');
    }
}
```

As you can see is the above code the problem. `item.get('category.id')` simple does always return undefined. However the Articles do have a category defined:

**REST response:** (including relationship values)

```
{
   "articles":[
      {
         "id":116,
         "name": "Article 1"
         "category":[
            11
         ],
      },
      {
         "id":115,
         "name": "Article 2"
         "category":[
            6
         ],
      },
      {
         "id":114,
         "name": "Article 3"
         "category":[
            11
         ],
      }
   ],
   "categories":[
      {
         "id":6,
         "name":"Category 1",
      },
      {
         "id":11,
         "name":"Category 2",
      }
   ],
}
```

Edit: `item.get('category')` does return a `<DS.ManyArray:ember747>` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it already.

HasMany is an Array of Objects. That way we have to use `findBy` to search for the ID. (correct me I am wrong).
Use `item.get('category').findBy('id', params.category)` to filter by ID.